# Paste label of grouping variable on stat_cor results

Tags: r, ggplot2, paste, ggpubr

I've this situation:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Load data
data("mtcars")
df <- mtcars
df$vs <- factor(df$vs, labels = c("Alpha", "Beta"))
df$MyFactor <- rep(c("White", "Black"), nrow(df)/2)


# Plotting
ggplot(df, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, group = vs))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  facet_wrap(~MyFactor)+
  stat_cor(method = "pearson", label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "left", color = "black")+
  theme_bw()
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

I would like to `paste` on the `stat_cor` labels the relative grouping variable `vs` (i.e. `Alpha` and `Beta`). Thus, I used:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, group = vs))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  facet_wrap(~MyFactor)+
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste(..group.., "- ", ..r.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~`,`~")), method = "pearson", label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "left", color = "black")+
  theme_bw()
```

However, my output is:

[image]

How can I get my vs grouping labels?

Answer (score 0):

I solve in this dirty way:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, group = vs))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  facet_wrap(~MyFactor)+
  stat_cor(aes(label = paste(factor(..group.., labels = c("A", "B")), "- ", ..r.label.., ..p.label.., sep = "~` `~")), method = "pearson", label.y.npc="top", label.x.npc = "left", color = "black")+
  theme_bw()
```

[image]